# Live reload is not working after upgrading to Gulp 4

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-connect

My gulpfile.js looks like below,

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var pug = require('gulp-pug');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-csso');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('connect', function () {
    connect.server({
        root: 'build',
        livereload: true,
        port: 3000
    });
});

gulp.task('html', function () {
    return gulp.src('client/html/**/*.pug')
        .pipe(pug({
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
        .pipe(connect.reload())
});

gulp.task('css', function () {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'client/scss/*.scss'])
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
        .pipe(connect.reload())
});

gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src(['client/assets/**/*.*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets'))
        .pipe(connect.reload())
});

gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src('client/javascript/*.js')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'))
        .pipe(connect.reload())
});

gulp.task('watch', gulp.parallel('html', 'css', 'js'));

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('connect', 'watch', 'html', 'css', 'images', 'js'));
```

When I run this code, I do not get any error on console, but also things do not auto reload on browser. I did this right with previous versions of Gulp, but unable to run it with Gulp 4 somehow. Now whenever I stop the server, I get below error,

```
[18:44:35] The following tasks did not complete: default, connect
[18:44:35] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your connect function to explicitly call done(); I think you'll need this when calling series() in Gulp 4

```
gulp.task('connect', function (done) {
    connect.server({
        root: 'build',
        livereload: true,
        port: 3000
    });

    done();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('html', (done) => 
   gulp.src('client/html/**/*.pug')
      .pipe(pug({
          pretty: true
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
      .on('end', () => { 
         connect.reload();
         done();
      });
);
```

Comment: Hi there, could you give a little explanation on how your code fixes the problem?

Comment: Most gulp plugins run between src & dest methods. Dest: Creates a stream for writing Vinyl objects to the file system. You must listen stream to complete the task.